# Doctrine self reference to parent

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, extends

Say for instance I have an extended repository in Symfony and the parent has been set as the fieldtype of another Repository. Will it be possible to set the sibling to the parents fieldtype?

Here's some (pseudo) code to clarify my question:

```
class User 
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected product;
}

class Product 
{
    protected price
}

class ProductList extends Product 
{
     /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     */        
     protected list;
}
```

Will it be possible to set a ProductList on the User's Product field?

Comment: I've tried that before and no, It doesn't work the way you want it to. Doctrine would persist a product even when you give it a productlist. And when you load it from the orm it will be a product not a productlist.

Comment: Is there any work-around or a different solution to this problem?

Comment: Couldn't you just set a ManyToMany relation to products on your User entity? Or if you really need the ProductList entity, set TargetEntity to ProductList on user and then you need to make a list even if you only have 1 product.

Comment: Could work. The thing is that id prefer to have a productlist rather than a product with self references to other products.